# Put some config files in /boot/

Tags: raspbian, wifi, boot, boot-issues, windows

I have a headless Rpi2/Raspbian that does nothing else than:

- connect to Wifi with this `/etc/network/interfaces`:

  ```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback
  allow-hotplug wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wpa-ssid "MyWifi"
  wpa-psk "<mypasswordhere>"
  allow-hotplug eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
  ```
- start radio with this `/etc/systemd/system_radio.service`:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Radio
  Wants=network-online.target
  After=network.target network-online.target
  [Service]
  Type=oneshot
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/mplayer http://example.com/livestream.mp3 &
  RemainAfterExit=yes
  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

It works.

Question: **how is it possible to move these 2 config files to `/boot/`, so that I can easily modify the config without SSH, without Linux, just from Windows (micro SD card in my laptop card reader)?** (`/boot/` is accessible from Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use symlinks:

```
rpi ~$ sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces /boot/
rpi ~$ sudo ln -s /boot/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces

rpi ~$ sudo mv /etc/systemd/system_radio.service /boot/
fpi ~$ sudo ln -s /boot/system_radio.service /etc/systemd/system_radio.service
```

Comment: Then `/boot/` has to be mounted by default on every boot. Is it the case by default? (No, IIRC). Should this be done in `fstab` or in `/boot/cmdline.txt` or elsewhere @Ingo?